How are military aviators call signs made?
Military aviators always have a call sign that they are referred to as. I would like to know how they are picked? Is it their personality, surname or what?

Are you specifically asking about US Naval aviators?

Canadians are trying to prevent offensive nicknames.

It is a completely random process, the same way civilians might pick a nickname, although perhaps slightly more intentional.

Think of when you were a kid... did you ever get teased about your name?  Well, that same playground name you hated back then becomes your call sign.

Did you ever do something stupid and get called some funny name to remind you of your error?  That too is fodder for a call sign.

Share a last name with a celebrity?  Your call sign might become that persons name. *

Super cool under stress, icewater in your veins, fast like a predator?  Nope.  Only if you are in the movies do you get a cool call sign like "Iceman", "Viper" etc.


While some call signs are cool and really funny, "Goose" is a much better example of the ordinary, pedestrian sort of names that are more common out there.
There's no special process, your peers will choose one for you.  It may change or evolve, or it may just stick.
What you can't do is choose one for yourself.  For a humorous and accurate example of how the process works, watch "The Maid" episode of Seinfeld where George Constanza attempts to get the nickname "T-Bone" but ends up with "Koko".

P.S. Mine was "Monty", after 1970s game show host Monty Hall.  It was assigned by an instructor during advanced training, and I was never interesting enough to earn another one so it just stuck...


It's how I ended up with Timbo. It was a minor character's name in a movie. I entered the room where my fellow student aviators were watching the movie... and I entered right after a funny scene that featured "Timbo." One of my friends pointed at me and said "Timmmmbbboooooo!" And it stuck ever since.

Reminds me of the Big Bang Theory episode in which Howard tried hard to get Rocketman for a nickname, but ended up with Froot Loops
